# Tkinter, update tree with sqlite3 : OperationalError: no such table: tree

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

A couple of days ago I started making my first GUI software and I reached the stage where I have set up my labels/buttons/entries, connected the entries to an SQL database, created a tree list that shows up in the frame I want, and populated the tree with the database (i.e. the correct entries show up in the correct columns in the tree) so all this works fine. 
Right now I don't have a correct function to update the tree, so each time I run the programme (for testing purposes), it has saved the current list of entries and adds the new ones over and over, so I have a list of dozens of rows from all the tests I have run.

Here is my attempt to add an update function:

```
def treeUpdate(): 
    for child in tree.get_children():          
        print(child)                       ## nothing is printed out here 
        tree.delete(child)
    c.execute('SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM tree')
    records = c.fetchall()
    for i in records: 
        tree.insert("", "end", text ="", values=(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3]))
    conn.close()
```

The error I Get is:

> OperationalError: no such table: tree

And here is part of the tree code:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(BottomFrame)
tree['columns'] = ('column1','column2', 'column3','column4')
tree.heading("#0", text = '', anchor = "w")
tree.column("#0", width = 5, anchor = 'center', stretch = tk.NO)
tree.heading("#1", text = 'File Name', anchor = "w")
tree.heading("#2", text = 'Archive Interval',anchor = "w")
tree.heading("#3", text = 'Delete Interval',anchor = "w")
tree.heading("#4", text = 'Output Directory',anchor = "w")
tree.pack(fill = "both")
print("tree created")         ## this is printed successfully
```

I get that tree is not an sql table, so I guess you can not use sql commands to manipulate the tree? Is there any other way this can be done? 
If it is of any help, I have included the update function in the function which adds the new entries to the database (see below), but not the function which retrieves the records and adds them to the tree.

```
def Add(): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('FilesToArchive.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Files VALUES (:Filename, :Time_Interval, :Delete_Interval, :Destination)",
            {
               'Filename': str(filedir.get()),
               'Time_Interval': Interval.get(),
               'Delete_Interval': DelInt.get(),
               'Destination': str(outputdir.get())
            }
        )
    conn.commit()       
    treeUpdate()
    #c.close()                          
    pass
```

Comment: The error is saying your database doesn't have a table named "tree". Does your database have a table named "tree"?

Comment: I get the tree I created is not a database, but I followed this code exactly from an online tutorial (or so I thought), so I assumed the error must be related to another part of my code. I tried different things but nothing seems to help

Comment: You need to read the error message. You are asking it to select data from a table named "tree" (`SELECT ... from tree')`. If this is exactly how the tutorial shows you, you need to pick a better tutorial.

Comment: According to your `Add()` function, you should use `SELECT * FROM Files` instead.